# could not create ipa file for distribution of archive the "saygoodbye" task was not given a value for the required parameter sessionid

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have created sample Xamarin froms application , I was able run the IOS application in mac in cloud.
Now i want to create the IPA file which can be installed in a mobile for testing .
But while distributing the Archive i am getting bellow error message .
Can some help to get this fixed.
**could not create ipa file for distribution of archive the "saygoodbye" task was not given a value for the required parameter sessionid**

I have created ad-hoc profile for App distribution

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Ixh.png)

Comment: What is the `saygoodbye` task in your project ?

Comment: I am not sure about it I have searched that word in the project but couldn't find it , This is my first project in xamarine

Comment: You could post the issue to **Help->Send Feedback -> report a problem** in VS .